# Stash parsing? Trying to compare a field from parent entry to field in child entry (Matrix + Playa)

Tags: matrix, playa, stash

I've been hacking at this for a good portion of my day, and I'm at a rather sturdy brick wall right now. Feels like the answer should be fairly obvious, but after trying every possible combination of settings, I'm thoroughly stuck.

(Backstory, not entirely relevant, perhaps: In a parent entry, I have a matrix, and in that matrix, I have a playa field. Additionally, I have a field (a single select dropdown) whose value I want to use in a conditional while looping through a matrix in the child entry. Have I lose anyone yet?)

Now, the stash item will show up while working in the parent entry's fields just fine but if I use `{exp:stash:get}` in the child entry, nothing shows up. The exception to this, however, is if the stash item is hardcoded. I found this out while seeing if it was even crossing over at all.

I've tried all sorts of combinations of settings, starting out very deliberately then moving on to smashing my keyboard hoping for the right combination of parameters while desperately searching my desk for bourbon.

I assumed, at least, using `parse_tags='yes'` would mean the contents of the Stash item were, essentially, hardcoded, no longer dependent on the rest of the template to work. Am I missing something?

(If I need to include code, I can, but it didn't seem entirely relevant.)

Comment: The code is relevant since we need it to understand the parse order. Please post it here and I'll take a look.

Comment: Vince, you should really post your code. Descriptions are not able to be enough, and Mark Croxton who's asked you to do it is the author of Stash, and very sharp. EE's own parse order is very intricate, and that's why the code needs to be shown, so that an expert can identify how to work with it.